# Nose-wrestling for political power - Is a human trunk possible in terms of evolution?

Tags: science-based, evolution, humans, space-colonization

In the far future, a planet in the Milky Way that was colonised by humans 500,000 years before has developed nose-wrestling as a means of establishing dominance.

This is thought to have begun with a fabled inhabitant who, by chance, had an unusually large and strong nose and used to jut it in the direction of opponents. He would even walk up to them and physically press his nose against theirs, thus intimidating them. Over generations this became fashionable and eventually a sign of dominance. Although nose fights can last for a long time, they are very rarely fatal so this is an efficient way of resolving conflicts.

**Question**

I want my humans to have developed a prehensile trunk with which they can wrestle. I am however concerned that there are evolutionary branches that may be dead ends. Is it too late for human noses to develop new sets of muscles and hence prehensility, or can evolution always find a way out of a dead end?

Note: If we are stuck in a blind alley with respect to prehensility, I wonder how noses *could* develop so as to best enable fighting.

Comment: "although fights can last for a long time... this is an efficient way of resolving conflicts" - this must be some new definition of "efficient" that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Cadence - I didn't say that fighting is a *good* way of resolving conflicts, but it is efficient. It is ubiquitous in Nature so there must be some utility in it.

Comment: The problem with "can X evolve?" questions is that, according to our present understanding of evolution, given enough time anything can evolve. The question isn't what attributes would evolve because that's unanswerable (they'll be what you, the author, want, see [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609)). A better question is, "here are the specific characteristics of my noses, what evolutionary pressures could lead to this?" because the question is much more deterministic.

Comment: @JBH - Thanks for that feedback. As no-one has answered yet, I will adopt a modified version of your suggestion.  Note that (a) I'm not certain that "given enough time" is guaranteed to be true, and (b) I have already defined the evolutionary pressures, i.e.  to win at nose battles.

Comment: I think that's a better question. (+1), especially since we're dealing with something that doesn't have significant (if any) musculature anymore. A good answer would look back to a creature in our distant past with a similar limitation and show how it evolved into something (frankly anything) involving musculature. Yeah, I like what you did a lot better.

Comment: @Cadence It's more efficient than World War One. Or Two. Etc.

Comment: The Panda's thumb may be a good model for evolving such a structure. However, 500K years would probably not be an adequate time scale to evolve a well adapted trunk. The elephant required several million years to evolve their trunks. The just-so-story you suggest here would not be adequate evolutionary pressure. Status in the tribe can be settled many other ways.

Comment: [Homunculus loxodontus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus_loxodontus) by Dutch sculptor Margriet van Breevoort. Very popular in Slavic Eastern Europe under the nickname [Zhdun](https://www.google.com/search?q=zhdun&gl=us&hl=en&tbm=isch).

Comment: I say that first nose-wrestler would have to withstand blasts of all sorts with his nose in order to transfer this habit. It's quite more likely (like 10^20 more likely) that one of those early nose-wrestlers would win a fight by nose then lose a fight by knife in that nose, thus this habit would die out before it'll be a factor in human evolution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more or less anything can evolve with sufficient time and proper selective pressure. Is your human trunk evolution probable? No, unless people who tend to lose those conflicts cannot reproduce.

But that is not all that important. If you colonized the galaxy it shouldn't be an issue doing some genetic engineering to introduce those trunks. In fact, even if society collapsed to medieval level of technology, it will be far faster to relearn everything to the point where such genetic manipulation would be possible, than waiting for natural evolution. And by far faster I mean orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Do you have any backup for the statement "more or less anything can evolve with sufficient time and proper selective pressure". That is a big part of my question. I don't imagine that an ant can evolve into a human no matter how long you selectively breed. The reason is that there are evolutionary cul-de-sacs. Evolution only goes forward it does not go back in time and start anew. Humans and elephants diverged about 60 million years ago. I need to know if humans have lost the genes for flexible noses or if they can develop new ones from scratch.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Why ants couldn't evolve to something resembling humans? There are cases where an organism became less complex, and later on more again. Mind you, it could take hundreds of milions of years... And new genes develop all the time! There are multiple mechanisms that can lead to new genes. Humans thou definitely don't have viable genes for flexible noses (well, technically no organism has "genes for flexible noses", but have genes for proteins that lead to formation of flexible noses), and it would take quite a bit of mutations to either reactivate one or form a new one.

Comment: I personally have some genes for flexible noses. I can constrict my nostrils to some extent voluntarily and even cause the tip of my nose to move slightly up and down. Judging by the work of animal breeders, it doesn't take 500,000 years to make substantial  morphological changes. I'm sure it would take less than 500,000 years to select for longer and longer noses and get something that was substantially longer than current humans. The question is can these plausibly become prehensile in the same amount of time.

Comment: Timescales of evolution depends on how heavy is selective pressure and how big of a change there is. And there are few to none cases of selective pressure more drastic than selective breeding, so that can happen quite quickly. Natural occurrences are way slower. Because people wouldn't just let them be selectively bred for stronger noses (in fact, only an insane AI would even attempt that). And your selective pressure is unlikely to be all that strong, unless losers of those arguments cannot reproduce. But as I said, whole evolution angle is meaningles in the face of genetic engineering.

Comment: It's not quite true that Chasly would need the losers to not reproduce. All that's needed is a *preference* that leads to greater desirability and, therefore, competition that wins better genetic provenance. Not reproducing would allow evolution to work faster, but reproducing wouldn't stop the process. What I might find unbelievable is a human preferring a trunk over a nose. But, then again, [many things are found attractive](https://www.pulse.ng/lifestyle/food-travel/why-girls-of-the-mursi-tribe-must-remove-their-teeth-and-stretch-their-lips-before/656yf4d).

Comment: @JBH It is unlikely that preference would remove normal noses from genepool. Unless there are also other drastic changes in humanity - because let's be honest, some people would definitely find normal noses kinky. Mah, it's not unbelievable that people would prefer a trunk over a nose, what is unbelievable that trunk-pushing would be a thing of dominance. A normal response of someone getting in your face is to punch them...

Comment: @Negdo - Male Peafowl have extravagant tails despite the fact that this make them easier prey for their natural predator the tiger. The male fiddler crab has one claw massively bigger than the other in defiance of the idea that Nature prefers symmetry.  My suggestion relates to Fischerian runaway selection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisherian_runaway

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica In those cases extravagant features present a significant advantage: it shows the subject has high biological fitness. Something that wouldn't happen in humans, as trunk doesn't "waste" resources aka show you have resources to waste. Face it, your desired feature is extremely unlikely to evolve naturally because the selective pressure is not strong enough. And let's be honest here, your proposed selective pressure is not all that good. If someone tried to "show dominance" to me with "pressing my nose", I would press my fist to his nose... We are violent monkeys after all

Comment: @Negdo - lol, and here I am trying to find a relatively peaceable way to solve disputes and you are advocating violence!

Comment: Yeah, keep in mind that despite Chasly's use of [tag:science-based], this site's primary purpose is suspension of disbelief. Don't worry about proving that Real Science won't allow it. Find a way to use Real Science to rationalize it.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica That is simple biology (not even psychology, as it goes deeper). If someone physically touch you as a show of dominance, the response is either subservience, or escalation. Take a wild guess what would someone physically stronger choose. Not that you cannot solve disputes non-violently: we do that now just fine, but your solution is extremely immersion-breaking (unless some serious genetic engineering is involved, including changes to the base human nature, in which case it would be easier to just change human behaviour)